# How to load data from saved file with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Spark provide method `saveAsTextFile` which can store `RDD[T]` into disk or hdfs easily.

T is an arbitrary serializable class.

I want to reverse the operation.
I wonder whether there is a `loadFromTextFile` which can easily load a file into `RDD[T]`?

Let me make it clear:

```
class A extends Serializable {
...
}

val path:String = "hdfs..."
val d1:RDD[A] = create_A

d1.saveAsTextFile(path)

val d2:RDD[A] = a_load_function(path) // this is the function I want

//d2 should be the same as d1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `d1.saveAsObjectFile(path)` to store and `val d2 = sc.objectFile[A](path)` to load.

I think you cannot `saveAsTextFile` and read it out as `RDD[A]` without transformation from `RDD[String]`

Answer (score 0):

To create file based RDD, We can use SparkContext.textFile API

Below is an example:

val textFile = sc.textFile("input.txt")

We can specify the URI explicitly.

If the file is in HDFS:
sc.textFile("hdfs://host:port/filepath")

If the file is in local:
sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/")

If the file is S3:

s3.textFile("s3n://mybucket/sample.txt");

To load RDD to Speicific type:

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val people = sc.textFile("employees.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))

Here, people will be of type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]

Comment: But it generates RDD[String], I need RDD[T].

Comment: I think Spark by default doesn't support this. But you can convert your original RDD to specific type. I am updating my answer. Please verify.